# How to get a query to count the total rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**How to get a query to count the total rows?**
My query:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace `select <whatever> ...` with `select count(*) ...`

Comment: I tried this, not working :( @dasblinkenlight

Comment: What is this - the contents of a table? The output of a T-SQL query?? Something else (if so: **what**??)

Comment: The output of a T-SQL query, @marc_s

Comment: |GeoEye 1 MS (2 m) Del  2011-03-28 Al 2015-02-10 | 218 | the result of adding the instruction "COUNT"

Comment: The distinct seems a bit unneccesairy when you already do a group by. Not sure if it makes any difference to count(*) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.WhateverYourTableIsCalled
```

**Update:** since this is a **query output**, you need to use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
     (...your current query here....)
```

or just call

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

after you've selected the data.

Comment: *not working* - ***how?!?!*** Do you get no result at all? A *wrong* result (how do you know it's wrong?)? Do you get an error - if so: ***what*** error??

Comment: I have no reputationtion to qualify positively, sorry :(

Comment: @MarinhadoNascimento: now you do have enough reputation to upvote :-))

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM dbo.TableName;
```

If you want to count the query result than

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (--sub query );
```

Or simply use

`SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`

Or You can also use following query if you want to count based on column

```
SELECT COUNT(ColumnName)FROM dbo.TableName;
```

Comment: @MarinhadoNascimento you can accept the ans if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of rows returned by your query, try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (<your query here>) AS results;
```